# How many licenses do I get when I buy Office Home and Business 2019

Tags: license, bug, microsoft-office-2019

I bought MS Office 2019 (Home & Business) and installed it on one Windows computer and 2 Macs. I looked up how many computers I could have and Microsoft themselves said that I had 25 licenses to use before I needed to get another key. However, when I tried to install on another Mac today in 2021, it tells me that the 'key is already used' and that I need another license. I want to keep from having to buy anything else, so which is it? 1 computer or 25?

Comment: Ask Microsoft...

Comment: I'd have bought the Mac version from the App Store - Apple believes in one licence per person [or per family if Family Sharing is supported], MS thinks it should be one licence per machine. Paradigm clash.

Comment: Microsoft have horrible licensing terms. You either buy it for silly money - £250 each, one license per user, or you can rent it for the whole family for £80 a year. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/buy/microsoft-365 I checked the Apple App Store & it is still dependant on this rental/subscription model. I'd seriously look into what you can do with Pages, Numbers etc instead - they're free ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Microsoft Office FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/office-home-business-2019/cfq7ttc0k7cq?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:faqtab)

> #### What is the maximum number of Office licenses I can activate using the same Microsoft account?
>
> Users can activate 1 subscription for Microsoft 365 Family and Microsoft 365 Personal and up to 25 licenses for Office Home & Student 2019, Office Home & Business 2019, and Office Professional 2019.

You can activate up to 25 licences **on your account**, it is not that you have 25 licences per copy bought. Just that you have used one licence applied to your account of the maximum 25.

Basically any single account ***can*** have 25 licences.

Each copy of [Office 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/p/office-home-business-2019) gives a single licence. That licence may well work across PC and Mac at the same time. I know in the past Microsoft allowed a licence to "activate" a single desktop computer and a single laptop computer but that does not sound like it is the case any more.

> - One-time purchase for 1 PC or Mac

If you need more than 1 machine then you need to buy more licences.

If Microsoft are saying you need more licences then you need more licences.

Comment: Well then I figured out a way to mess w/ the system bc I have it on 3 computers already

Comment: Activation is a weird and arcane labyrinth and only Microsoft know the true details. You may find that one more more of your computer is suddenly not activated or they may last a while. All we know is what is on their site. Their specific [Microsoft License Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Office/2019Professional/Useterms_Retail_Office_2019Professional_English.htm) state that only one device is allowed. Once you start actually *using* it then things may change...